# Construct a convex optimization problem to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^m{(|a_i^T x| - 1)^2}$

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization

I'm studying for an exam and came across a practice problem that I've been unable to solve.

> Let $a_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then answer the questions pertaining to the following optimization problem
>
> \begin{align} & \underset{x}{\text{minimize}} & & f_0(x) = \sum_{i=1}^m{(|a_i^T x| - 1)^2} \end{align}
>
> **a)** Is this a convex optimization problem?
>
> **b)** Formulate this problem
>       as one of the standard problems from class; that is, as a linear program (LP), quadratic program (QP), quadratically constrained quadratic program (QCQP), second order cone program (SOCP), geometric program (GP) or semidefinite program (SDP).

I can answer part a. This clearly isn't convex in general.

---

**Proof:** If we consider the case where $m=1$ then consider the values $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $a_1^T x_1 = -1$ and $x_2 = -x_1$ so $a_1^T x_2 = 1 \Rightarrow f_0(x_1)=0$ and $f_0(x_2)=0$. We find that $f_0(1/2 x_1 + 1/2 x_2) = f_0(0) = 1 > 0 = 1/2 f_0(x_1) + 1/2 f_0(x_2)$ which contradicts the claim that $f_0$ is convex. Also, the objective is not concave (fairly clear using similar argument).

---

I'm stuck at part b. I can formulate this problem as a set of quadratic programs by considering the fact that we want $a_i^T x$ to be near $1$ or $-1$. So we can solve this by considering the $2^m$ different quadratic programs

\begin{align}
& \underset{x}{\text{minimize}}
& & f_0(x) = \sum_{i=1}^m{(s_{i,k} a_i^T x - 1)^2}
\end{align}

where $k = 1,\ldots,2^m$ defines $2^m$ different optimization problems where where $s_{i,k} \in \{-1,1\}$ is every permutation of $-1$ and $1$.

An optimal point for the original problem is an optimal point of the above problem for the $k$ which gives the lowest optimal value.

I'm fairly certain this is not the answer the problem writer had in mind but I'm struggling to come up with a single convex optimization problem which can solve this problem. Can anybody help me come up with such a solution?

Comment: You are correct it is not a convex problem. And because it is not, part (b) cannot be done.

Comment: Doesn't necessarily follow. Counterexample: $\min\{\Phi(x)|a\leq x \leq b\}$ where $\Phi{x}$ is monotonic increasing and not convex then this is equivalent to LP $\min\{x | a \leq x \leq b \}$

Comment: fair enough, but I would argue that you’re solving a different problem in the second case. Equivalent, but different. For instance, geometric programs are not convex, but can be converted by a change of variables to a convex form. That doesn’t mean you’ve expressed the _original_ problem as a standard convex program, you are solving a different one.

Comment: True. To clarify, the question implies I'm looking for an equivalent problem.

Comment: Yes, but in your example, the feasible set is convex, and no change of variables is needed. And in my GP example, the fact that a change of variables produces a convex problem implies that the original problem had a convex optimal set. In this case we have an objective function that has to have multiple local minima.

Comment: Furthermore I am not convinced that your $2^m$-exploded version is correct. You can’t just pick the sign combinations that minimize the objective function. You have to pick the sign combinations that correspond to the signs of $a^Tx$ at the solution.

Comment: @Michael Grant Ah that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can come up with is $2^m$ sub problems.

The idea is straightforward, similar to your idea, except with the addition of constraints which essentially partition the feasible space so that the objective is convex on each partition.

The idea is illustrated with the function $x \mapsto (|x|-1)^2$. Split
into the two QPs $\min \{ ((x-1)^2 | x \ge 0 \}$ and
$\min \{  (-x-1)^2 | x \le 0 \}$.

Formally, if $\sigma \in \{\pm 1\}^m$, define the subproblem
$P_\sigma: \ \min \{ \sum_m (\sigma_i a_i^T x-1)^2 | \sigma_i a_i^T x \ge 0 \}$.

Comment: I don't understand why the second constraint is $\leq$ and not $\geq$, could you elaborate on how you got here?

Comment: I have corrected my answer. Note that at a solution we must have $y_i = ||a_i^Tx|-1|$.

Comment: okay. I think I understand. Just to make sure. If you let $y_i=||a_i^T x| - 1|$ then substitute into $f_0$ you get an equivalent problem. Furthermore, $y_i \geq ||a_i^T x| - 1|$ is fine because if equality doesn't hold then the objective is clearly not optimized. Finally you remove the absolute values by replacing each $y_i$ inequality by the 4 inequality constraints you use?

Comment: My apologies, I am still wrong.

Comment: The above is at attempt to atone for my earlier suggestions, albeit not a very practical attempt.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and correcting my mistake. Your solution makes sense. I'll still digesting @Micheal Grant's comment about it not being possible for a single problem solution existing. I'll leave this open before accepting the answer for a couple more days or until I'm convinced that no solution exists.